# I am always very P.C

Tags: riddle

Here is a riddle I have. Can you solve it?

I am very P.C.
Anytime I go anywhere, I carry 3, 2, 1, and 4.
Why?

Hint 1:

> P.C. does not stand for politically correct

Hint 2:

> I carry them in my pocket

Comment: because you are very P.C :)

Comment: A hint maybe?.. Not enough of them...

Comment: @nicael there you go.  Will do another one later if still no guesses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am very P.C.

> pocket change

Anytime I go anywhere, I carry 3, 2, 1, and 4.
Why?

> 3 quarters, 2 dimes, 1 nickel and 4 pennies can make any amount of change for a dollar

Comment: I was thinking "precise" for the first word, but yeah, that's it

Answer (score 0):

Do you carry:

> 4 cell phones?

I am very P.C.

> P.C. can mean personal computer, of which cell phones are a kind of.

Anytime I go anywhere, I carry 3, 2, 1, and 4.

> You carry 4 cell phones, so you also carry 3 cell phones (pick any three of the four) along with 2 and 1 cell phone(s).

Hint 1:

> Personal Computer != Politically Correct

Hint 2

> Cell phones are generally carried in one's pocket.